# VSCode/Pylance converts network drive to UNC path

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

I have a python file on a network drive (X:\foo.py). If I click on a python function defined in the same file and press F12 (go to definition), VSCode opens a *new window* where the file name is \\some.unc.path\foo.py
This behavior is recent but downgrading VSCode to an older version didn't help.
Is there a setting perhaps that makes VSCode convert network mapped drives to UNC?

Comment: Why?  The UNC path works everywhere, even if the mapping isn't renewed.

Comment: @TimRoberts The problem is it opens a new window. So all of a sudden you have 2 windows open for the same file and they're not in sync. VSCode doesn't seem to understand you're editing the same file in those 2 windows.

Comment: Will it work if you open your workspace from the UNC path directly instead of the mapped drive?

Comment: I've raised an issue ticket: https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/5395. now waiting for maintainer response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This was a bug introduced in v2023.12.1 of the Pylance extension.** The canonical issue ticket is at [Go to definition not working in network drive after updating Pylance from 2023.11.10 to 2023.12.1 #5260](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/5260).

**It's fixed in [pre-release version 2023.12.104](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/releases/tag/2023.12.104)** ([source](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/5260#issuecomment-1904708376)). You can switch to the pre-release channel (either right click the extension item in the Extensions View and click "Switch to Pre-Release Version", or left click, and click the button with the same text in the opened extension page). The related changelog entry is [here](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#202312104-22-January-2024-PreRelease). Once the next release version comes out after that pre-release version, it should have the fix as well.

FYI: I found out about this by contacting the maintainers with a question issue ticket (granted, you kind of have to know the right repo to raise an issue ticket in, and check whether they accept question issue tickets): [Has something changed recently that causes Go To Definition to open files with network-share-drive paths converted to UNC paths?
#5395](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/5395).

Answer (score 2):

I work on pylance. This is a bug we introduced in 2023.12.1. It is not intentional. We've recently posted a new prerelease that should fix the issue.

The latest release here should have the fix:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance