# Why does the file open twice, one not editable?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Why do two windows pop up when I open a file in vscode? One of them is normally editable, and the other one can't do anything.

[image: the one that can't do anything]

[image: the normal one]

vscode version:

```
版本: 1.87.2 (system setup)
提交: 863d2581ecda6849923a2118d93a088b0745d9d6
日期: 2024-03-08T15:20:17.278Z
Electron: 27.3.2
ElectronBuildId: 26836302
Chromium: 118.0.5993.159
Node.js: 18.17.1
V8: 11.8.172.18-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22621
```

I tried setting `workbench.editor.enablePreview` to false, but it just made the file name not italicized.

Comment: I have no idea why this is happening, but just wanted to say welcome back to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. Writing a good title is important for communicating the problem (see [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask)), so I wrote a better one for you, but of course you can [edit] it yourself if you want.

Comment: Welcome! 1) Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: 2) if you're using a network drive, check if your question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/77861942/11107541